# How to fix React useState still keep using old code?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
export default function Home() {
const { all_post } = useSelector(state => state.PostReducers);
const changeCategory = (category) => {
      let filtered_posts
      if (category==="all") {
         filtered_posts = all_post
      }
      else {
        filtered_posts = all_post.filter(ap => ap.categories[0].title === category);
      }
      return ( <div>{category}</div> )

}

const [post_bycategory, set_post_bycategory] = useState(changeCategory("all"));
return (
      <div>
        <button className='text-2xl mt-2' onClick={() = 
          {set_post_bycategory("Criticism")}}>Criticism</button>
        </button>
        <div className="col-span-5 md:col-span-10"> 
          {post_bycategory}
        </div>
      </div>
)}
```

Then I changed my changeCategory function render to
`return (<div> Hello {category} </div>)`
How on Earth it still render the old code, even though I have saved, restart React, and restart my browser?
I have even tried to change the variable, but magically, it still render the same, even though my old code has been deleted for about an hour.

Comment: Did you try to right click on the refresh button on your browser, then click on hard reload and reset cache?

Comment: @JimmySoussan Yes, I even tried to use it in a completely new browser (Chrome, normally I use Edge), which I have never opened before